# Is openshift origin 1.4 can work on Ubuntu？

Tags: ubuntu, openshift-origin

I just have installed openshift origin 1.4 by openshift ansible on centos7. it is
one master two nodes structure.
Can I also install origin 1.4 by openshift ansible on Ubuntu？

Answer (score 2):

As described [here](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/install/prerequisites.html) Ubuntu isn't supported as operating system for an openshift environment:

> Base OS: Fedora 21, CentOS 7.3, or RHEL 7.3 with the "Minimal"
>   installation option and the latest packages from the Extras channel,
>   or RHEL Atomic Host 7.3.2 or later. RHEL 7.2 is also supported using
>   Docker 1.12 and its dependencies.